# Photo app album sync to Onedrive

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview, onedrive, photos

I am running [build 10549](http://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/10/14/announcing-windows-10-mobile-insider-preview-build-10549/) and have made an album in the photo app. It says that the album is only local. How can I get it to sync to onedrive?
Photo backup/upload is on and working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to sync albums across devices. There are quite a few entries for this in the Windows Feedback app that you can vote on.

A workaround would be to actually create the album on OneDrive rather than on the device (via the OneDrive app or a browser). This still wouldn't be a complete solution, but should be closer to what you want.

Comment: I have not found this in the feedback app. Will try again. Thanks!

Comment: Filter by Apps and Games > Photos > Search for "Album sync."

Comment: I also filtered by my build and suggestion (instead of problem) and got no results. also with my build and problem there is no issue with album keyword. app -> photo -> trending. Perhaps because I am dutch.